# Mysql : load data inserting 0 instead of null

Tags: mysql, database

Problem: above mentioned load data query inserting 0 instead of null for price field(column)

Mysql Query :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/data.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE bug_repeat 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

file `data.csv` content is as below

```
name,\N
name,3
```

`bug_repeat` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `bug_repeat` (
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,6) DEFAULT NULL  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note: above query is not working on one of MYSQL server but exact same query working fine on two other MYSQL server. I don't know what going wrong. Can some please let me know what is the exact issue.( all MYSQL servers(version 5.7.22) are on Ubuntu 16.xxx OS). I am getting same problem for bigint data type as well.
show warnings result:
1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'price' at row 1

Comment: Are all of the tables on each server defined exactly the same? What do you mean by **"not working"**?

Comment: yes. the table is exactly same on three database server. not working means. value \N inserted as 0(zero) instead of NULL. on other two servers \N value properly inserted as NULL.

Comment: According to documentation
`If the FIELDS ESCAPED BY character is empty, escape-sequence interpretation does not occur.` so `NULL` values will be inserted as text I guess. But by default it is `ESCAPED BY '\\'` so probably this is not the case.